# HandlerInterceptorAdapter doesn't seem to forward HttpServletRequestWrapper

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, interceptor

I'm trying to create a validation system for my JSON webservices.  The idea is to have an interceptor catch every Json `@RequestBody`, make a JSON object with it by means of `JacksonMapping`.  Then read `ValidationAnnotations` from it to check the data and when passes complete the regular flow otherwhise send back to sender with a modelandviewmap containing the error messages.

Knowing this context consider this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/contact/list/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody JsonContactList findFilteredContacts(@RequestBody JsonContactSelectorData selectorData, Model model) throws Exception {
    MbaLog.debugLog(logger,"Finding Contacts with selector data: " + selectorData);     
    JsonContactList result = contactService.findContacts(selectorData);
    return result;
}
```

This is my controller method that the interceptor will be before, following is the interceptor

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    ValidationRequestWrapper wrapper = new ValidationRequestWrapper(request);
    //do complex validation here 
    return super.preHandle(wrapper, response, handler);
}
```

Next on the list is the requestwrapper

```
public class ValidationRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private String jsonString;

    public ValidationRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        jsonString = "";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
        if (scanner.hasNext())
            jsonString = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("need a break");
    }

    @Override  
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream ()   
        throws IOException {   

        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes());   
        ServletInputStream inputStream = new ServletInputStream() {   
            public int read ()    
                throws IOException {   
                return byteArrayInputStream.read();   
            }   
        };   
        return inputStream;   
    }   
}
```

As you can see, I grab the request input stream and then override the `getInputStream()` as is custom to do in these situations.  In the interceptor you can see me instantiate this wrapper and pass it on to the super.prehandle(...).  I expected to then enter the controller and work happily further with my jsonobject.  However the result is rather dissapointing.

```
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
```

The overriden inputstream method doesn't seem to be called ?  Or do I have this mechanic completly wrong?  Can I even use a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure out that it is not possible with a HandlerInterceptorAdapter to do the functionality I requested in my question.

My only option to fix this was to use a javax.servlet.Filter

example

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    InterceptorRequestWrapper myRequestWrapper = new InterceptorRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
    String httpRequestMethod = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod();
    if("POST".equals(httpRequestMethod) || "PUT".equals(httpRequestMethod)){
        String body = myRequestWrapper.getBody();
        ErrorObject errorObject = new ErrorObject();
        errorObject.setSource(body);
        Map<String, List<ErrorMessage>> errorMessages = new HashMap<String, List<ErrorMessage>>();
        ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage();
        error.setErrorLabel("myerror");
        errorMessages.put("test", Arrays.asList(error));
        errorObject.setErrorMessages(errorMessages);
        myRequestWrapper.setAttribute("errorObject", errorObject);
    }
    chain.doFilter(myRequestWrapper, response);
}
```